# Proposition formula splitting method? -Truth table generator(py)

Tags: python, truthtable, propositional-calculus

I have been working on this project and came to this trouble on the process of obtaining the parts of the formula for a separate evaluation.

Like for example: *(~p>~q)^(~(p^q))*

I should get:

1. *(~p)*
2. *(~q)*
3. *(~p>~q)*
4. *(p^q)*
5. *(~(p^q))*
6. *(~p>~q)^(~(p^q))*

I managed to get the most basic ones like 1,2,3 and 4 but from there i haven't managed to get the 5 and 6.

This website shows exactly  how I want to do it: [Truth table generator](https://trutabgen.com/)

Comment: This requires a parser, something which is a bit too broad for a single Stack Overflow question. If you want to stick to standard libraries, one possibility is to replace negation with `-`, and with `*` and or with `+`, let the `ast` module parse the resulting expression, and then walk the resulting parse tree.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.